# _delegate respondsToSelector:selector is not calling the method

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I have one class and one view controller. class has _delegate respondsToSelector:selector. But it is not calling the method(selector). After viewing my code below, would you please tell what am I doing wrong. FYI, This code worked before, but suddenly stopped working.

MyClass.h:

```
@protocol MyClassDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
-(void) receivedEvent:(TripEvent *) event;
@end

@interface MyClass : NSObject<MyClassEngine>

@property(assign) id<MyClassDelegate> delegate;
@property BOOL delegateOnMainThread;

-(id) initWithDelegate:(id<UbiTripRecorderDelegate>) tripDelegate
      onMainThread:(BOOL) onMainThread;

- (void) dispatchDelegate:(SEL)selector
           withObject:(id)obj;
```

MyClass.m contains the following code:

```
#import "MyClass.h"

@implementation MyClass
....
....
-(void) startPlaying {
    [self dispatchDelegate:@selector(receivedEvent:) withObject:newEvent];

}

- (void) dispatchDelegate:(SEL)selector   withObject:(id)obj {
   @try {
      if(_delegate && [_delegate respondsToSelector:selector]) {
       NSLog(@"I can't come to this point");
       }
    }
}
```

I've also added the following code in my view controller (MyViewController.h):

```
@interface MyViewController : BaseViewController<MyClassDelegate>
```

And finally implemented the method in MyViewcontroller.m :

```
-(void) receivedEvent : (TripEvent *) event {
    NSLog(@"I'm called");
}
```

The problem is that the  if(_delegate && [_delegate respondsToSelector:selector]) - logic never return true. Can anybody please check the code and let me know, if anything is wrong with my code?

Comment: Is `-(void) receivedEvent:(TripEvent *) event` implemented on `MyClass.m`?

Comment: Yes, it is implemented on MyViewController.m; But not declared in header file MyViewController.h; Can I make a problem?

Comment: Yes, _delegate is nil.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `_delegate` is not `nil`, otherwise the if statement is never true.

Also you can simplify

`if(_delegate && [_delegate respondsToSelector:selector])`

to

`if([_delegate respondsToSelector:selector])`

because message send to `nil` always return 0 or NO. In this case `[_delegate respondsToSelector:selector]` will return NO if _delegate is `nil`

Also, you did not declare a method in header will not cause any runtime difference. It may have compiler warning/error if such method not found.

Comment: Can you please tell me why delegate is nil in this case and how can I fix it?

Comment: you need to assign something to it

Comment: Update: delegate is still nil - But selector / method is called properly. Seems problem is unknown. Cause, sometime, it's working some time it's not working.